# Event of StatelessLinks in WebMarkupContainer don't fire

Tags: wicket

I have a form with a `StatelessLink` ("Delete profile?"). When this link is clicked a `WebMarkupContainer` is made visible containing two more links ("Really delete profile!" and "Cancel").

Java:

```
private StatelessLink deleteProfileWarningLink;
private WebMarkupContainer deleteProfileContainer;
private StatelessLink deleteProfileLink;
private StatelessLink deleteProfileCancelLink;    

public MyForm() {
    ...
    deleteProfileWarningLink = new StatelessLink("profileDeleteWarningLink") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            deleteProfileWarning();
        }
    };

    deleteProfileContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("deleteProfileContainer");
    deleteProfileContainer.setVisible(false);

    deleteProfileLink = new StatelessLink("reallyDeleteProfileLink") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            deleteProfile();
        }
    };

    deleteProfileCancelLink = new StatelessLink("cancelDeleteProfileLink") {
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            cancelDeleteProfile();
        }
    };

    ...

    add(deleteProfileWarningLink);
    deleteProfileContainer.add(deleteProfileLink);
    deleteProfileContainer.add(deleteProfileCancelLink);
    add(deleteProfileContainer);
}
```

And some HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <div wicket:id="deleteProfileContainer" class="deleteProfil">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a wicket:id="reallyDeleteProfileLink" class="button delete">Really delete profile!</a>
            <a wicket:id="cancelDeleteProfileLink" class="button cancel">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="unitA">
        <a wicket:id="profileDeleteWarningLink" class="button delete">Delete profile?</a>
    </span>
</fieldset>
```

However the events of the `StatelessLink`s in the `WebMarkupContainer` never fire.

Comment: I assume #cancelDeleteProfile() calls deleteProfileContainer#setVisible(true)? When deleteProfileLink/deleteProfileCancelLink are clicked, a new page instance is created and the container is no longer visible.

Comment: deleteProfileWarning() calls `deleteProfileContainer.setVisible(true)`, cancelDeleteProfile() sets it to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should optimize this with some custom JavaScript.
The idea is the following: Wicket generates all three buttons in the initial version of the page. The first button is initially visible and uses JavaScript to show the initially hidden (CSS, display:none) container with the other two buttons. The rest is as it is now.

Recently we discussed something related to your problem in dev@ mailing list: 
http://markmail.org/message/dkmxw4urqm444ryc